# How to remove a user account in Windows SBS 2011 but still deliver mails to another user?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

I have a user account (let's call him "Joe") in Windows SBS 2011 which should be deleted. But the email address associated with Joe's account should then belong to another user (let's call him "Jack").

In the end all mails addressed to joe@company.com should land in the Inbox of jack@company.com and the SBS account "Joe" should be deleted.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put an alias on jack's accounts for joe@company.com after you delete joe@company.com's user account and mailbox.

Steps:

1. I'm going to assume you've already used the SBS 2011 console to remove the user and their mailbox.
2. Open up the Exchange Management Console and go to Microsoft Exchange >> Recipient Configuration >> Mailbox and find the user Jack.
3. Right click >> Properties
4. E-Mail Addresses tab
5. Click "Add..." and put in the email address joe@company.com

[image]